# netbeans window that shows errors/warnings in files in form of a tree structure

Tags: java, netbeans

I used to have a window that show me in a explorer tree structure where my errors and warnings where, but now i dont know how to show it again, i'm using `netbeans 8.0.2.`

I don't think it was a plugin, i think it was by default. i have seen other questions but the all refer to the action task list that show the errors in a list and i already have that.

Or if there's already a plugin to do this i would like to try it.

I'm sorry that i dont have a picture do show how was the window that i want to show again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are talking about [Static Code Analysis](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/code-inspect.html)

[image]

You can found it in *source* / *inspect*

[image]